# How to move UIImageView while resizing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I'm trying to move a `UIImageView` up and down while making it bigger. Now when I do those things separately it works like I thought it would, but when i combine them it looks really glitchy and like I wanted it to look.

Here is my code so you can copy it into Xcode and see what happens for yourself.
Add a `UIImageView` with whatever image you got in interface builder and add this code to the viewController.h:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *bg1;

int steps;

float a;
```

And this to the viewController.m

```
#define kA 3

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    steps = 0;

    a = kA;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.04 target:self selector:@selector(walk)
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)resetA { // This function makes it possible for the UIImageView to move up and down
    if (a > 0) a=-kA;
    else a=kA;

    steps++;
    NSLog(@"%i", steps);
}

-(void)walk { // This function makes the UIImageView bigger and move up and down
    if (a > 0) [bg1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bg1.bounds.size.width+a,  
                                              bg1.bounds.size.height+a)];
    else [bg1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, bg1.bounds.size.width-a, 
                                        bg1.bounds.size.height-a)];

    [bg1 setCenter:CGPointMake(160, bg1.center.y+a)];
    a *= 0.9;

    if (a < 0.15 & a > 0 || a > -0.15 & a < 0) [self resetA];
}
```

Comment: It might be worthwhile to A) add an image or two to your question to show what you mean by "glitchy" and B) make a small test project available for people to download and look at.  Asking people to create a new project, drop your source code in, add some images, then compile it, etc. has a few too many steps for this to be worthwhile.

Comment: Ok I will add a link to the project, sorry if I disrespected you guys.

Comment: Tips: 1) Use a [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) instead of a scheduled timer. 2) Use setCenter and setBounds instead of setFrame and setCenter. SetFrame (check out [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)) sets bounds and center at the same time

Comment: Thank you setBounds worked :)